# Indentation of tabular-like environments in AUCTeX 11.88

Tags: indentation, emacs, auctex

AUCTeX 11.88 introduced a new style of indentation for tabular-like environments.  I understand this is implemented in LaTeX-indent-tabular.  Is there an easy way to revert to the old style?

Comment: Try to customize `LaTeX-indent-environment-list`: `M-x customize-variable RET LaTeX-indent-environment-list RET` and remove `LaTeX-indent-tabular` from the tabular-like entries.

Comment: @giordano It worked. Thanks!  Incidentally, I think the new indentation style is an improvement for tabulars with simple entries, but not for tabulars with complex entries.

Comment: Thanks for the report.  Luckily, I usually have to deal with simple tables ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can restore the old behavior by removing `LaTeX-indent-tabular` from `LaTeX-indent-environment-list`: <kbd>M-x</kbd> `customize-variable` <kbd>RET</kbd> `LaTeX-indent-environment-list` <kbd>RET</kbd> and remove all `LaTeX-indent-tabular` occurrences from tabular-like entries.

Comment: Oh yes, the new indentation is so painful for complex tabulars

Comment: Rather then removing them from the list, there are checkboxes in the customization dialog, so that you can turn them on and off according to the editing task at hand (click Apply after you made your selection).  For complex tabulars I usually turn them off, while for simple tabulars I turn them on.