# Indentation inside align environment in Emacs + AUCTeX

Tags: indentation, emacs, auctex

I use Emacs + AUCTeX for writing LaTeX. I want in my code to have 4 spaces of indentation so I used these in my `.emacs` file:

```
(setq LaTeX-indent-level 4) 
(setq LaTeX-item-indent 0)
```

Everything works fine and I have indentation of 4 spaces in `itemize`, `enumerate`, `equation` and `gather` but the indentation inside `align` environment remains 2 spaces. Why is that? Is this indented to happen and I need to change it manually or is it a bug?

Comment: Does it help if you follow the instructions in [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/241786/76063)?

Answer (score 4):

Customize LaTeX-indent-environment-list: `M-x customize-variable RET LaTeX-indent-environment-list RET` and uncheck `align` and `align*`